# Unable to clear the input field after submitting the form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, fetch-api

```
function Search() {
    let [state, setState] = useState({
        query: "",
        results: []
    })
let handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(state.query.length>0) {
            fetch(searchURL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setState(prevValue => {
                return {
                    ...prevValue,
                        results: data.Search
                }
            })) 
setState({query:""})
        }

    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Search</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." onChange={handleChange} value={state.query}/>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

After submitting the form, if I am setting the state, as in setState{query:""} , the API call is failing. How to acheive this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **the [`fetch` API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwje-YaCp87pAhUdURUIHbSMCr0QFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FFetch_API&usg=AOvVaw1bi4jzAjUAg2OvX8ufB00v) is asynchronous** (your `then` chains will not immediately execute after `fetch` execution and it will wait until the `fetch` get resolved) **you should add `setState({query:""})` inside your last `then` promise chain**.

So your code should be something like this:

```js
.then(data => setState(prevValue => {
  return {
    ...prevValue,
    query: "",
    results: data.Search
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do.
In your second then, you can change the code there to be

```
.then(data => setState(prevValue => {
  return {
   ...prevValue,
    results: data.Search
    query: ''
   }
}))
```

You can omit the `...prevValue` if you do not want to compute anything based on the previousState value

Or you can reset the form on success by calling `e.target.reset()`but since you are using the input as a controlled component. Go for the first alternative

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used hooks too often, but I believe if you replace `...prevValue` with `query: ''`.  That should work?

Answer (score 0):

setState(prevValue => {

```
            prevValue.query = "";

            prevValue.results= data.Search;   

            return {...prevValue};
```

});

```
}
```

Note : when you are updating any state , you can modify prevState variable just remember to return it as new deep cloned value for performance and correct practice.

Note: updating state is an async operation .

Comment: This is working with a slight change. In the handle submit function after making the API call, added the following code setState(prevValue => {
            return{
                ...prevValue,
                query: ""
            }
        })
It is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`query` has to be cleared after you receive the response like below:

```
{
      ...prevValue,
     results: data.Search,
     query: ""
}
```